# Why is the integrating factor of $y' + \frac{y}{x}$ is $x$ and not $|x|$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

For example, in the differential equation $y' + \frac{y}{x} = 3$, the integrating factor should be $e^{\int \frac1x dx} = e^{\ln|x|} = |x|$, but usually $x$ is used instead.

I investigated it a little and it seems like somehow both $x$ and $|x|$ would work: if we multiply through by $x$, $(xy)' = xy' + y$. But also, if we multiply through by $|x|$,
$$(|x|y)' = |x|y' + {\rm sgn}(y)y = |x|y' + \frac{|x|}{x}y.$$

Comment: Your domain cannot contain both positive and negative $x$-values, and if $\mu$ is an integrating factor, so is $-\mu$ (why?).

Comment: Why can't the domain contain both positive and negative values?

Comment: Because $x=0$ is not in the domain.

Comment: I think that boils down to the same question, but the answer doesn't really explain why, only that both ln(x) and ln|x| happen to work. And I think this question is more focused on the ln(x) vs ln|x| for future readers

Comment: @JoeC. Actually, in that previous answer, $\ln(x)$ does not just *happen* to work, and the answer does explain how retaining the absolute value symbol then taking cases returns the same solution as just dropping the absolute value symbol. In any case, here's a more explicit (and general) justification: [Deciding when to drop the absolute values in differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3807340/21813). Hope it helps!

Comment: Here's another very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230736/is-it-necessary-to-consider-absolute-values-when-solving-the-differential-equati